# Is it possible to add an a handler to JUL on AppEngine?

Tags: google-app-engine, guice, java.util.logging, handlers

I have an AppEngine application with Java.
I am using JUL (java.util.logging) to log the server side logs. 
I am creating a facade call CustomLogger in which it creates a JUL logger in the constructor using the factory:

```
@Inject
public CustomLogger( EmailLoggingHandler handler ){
    this.logger = Logger.getLogger( "ServerLogger" );
    logger.addHandler( handler );
}
```

Instance of CustomLogger is bind as eagerSingleton meaning only one instance of this class will ever be instantiated per Guice instance.
Everything was working until I injected the custom logger (EmailLoggingHandler) which is also part of dependency tree as a eagerSingleton.

```
   @Inject
    public EmailLoggingHandler( SendEmailHelper emailHelper ){
        this.emailHelper = emailHelper;
        setLevel(Level.SEVERE);
    }
```

The error I am getting:

```
Error injecting constructor, java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.util.logging.LoggingPermission control)
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: did the answer solve your problem? or did you just accept it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I tried to hook my handler into JUL on AppEngine. I solved it by avoiding any calls to `setLevel()` and just using my own level variable:

```
public class MyHandler extends Handler {

    private Level logLevel = Level.INFO;

    @Override
    public void publish(final LogRecord record) {
        if (record.getLevel().intValue() >= logLevel.intValue())
            // ...
    }

    ...

    public void setLogLevel(final Level lvl) {
        logLevel = Level.FINE;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the problem the questioner had. He had an AccessControlException when injecting the constructor - i.e before he had even reached the setLevel(). You need to read the question.

Comment: From my experience the problem _is_ the setLevel (and setFormatter).  I can add a logger (at the top level) without a security violation in startup code, although not in the properties file where a security violation _does_ occur.